# How to bind the contents of a combo box to the value of another

Tags: ms-access

I currently have two comboboxes on a form. The first combobox contains a list of items. I want the second combobox to repopulate whenever the first one is changed. The query that returns contents of the second box will use the PK value from the first box.

So basically the second combobox is bound to the query (example):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.description
FROM a
WHERE a.FK = [forms]![cbo1]
```

really generic example. This isn't working for me right now. Is there a way to do this, or am i going to have to do it in code?

Comment: Please, after 9 months and 67 questions, stop tagging your titles and start formatting your posts. We're getting a bit tired of having to edit every post you write!

Comment: sorry about the formatting. complaining about the title tagging is a bit much though. Never saw a problem with it and never got any complaints.

Comment: Well, now you have! We already have a consistent, indexable tagging system. Tags in titles are just messy and redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an onChange event to the first box. Click on the properties of the first box, then on the event tab and the elipses(...) next to the onChange field. Pick the code editor that will take you to a VBA window where you can instruct the second box to refresh. So if your second combo box is called cmbA you would have

```
cmbA.Requery
```

in the event handler method.

Comment: got right after is submitted. i forgot to reference the form name! i'll accept your answer soon as the timer is up lol. thanks

Comment: OnChange is not the appropriate event -- it fires for every keystroke -- you'd use the AfterUpdate event, instead.