# MS-Access, form to view one entry from one to many relationship

Tags: forms, ms-access, one-to-many

I have a table with Orders and a subtable with itemId's (one to many relationship)

In the form i have a Combobox to select a specific Order and another Combobox to select a specific itemId.

For this i have made a Query to view all aviable itemId's in the second Combobox.

I dont know how to view the selected itemId-data in the form.

Comment: Why are you not using a subform as suggested to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883128/ms-access-form-that-adds-info-to-a-one-to-many-relationship/10884203#10884203

Comment: This is another form where i want the operator to view the data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind the contents of a combo box to the value of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727297/how-to-bind-the-contents-of-a-combo-box-to-the-value-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Where argument of the Openform action to specify the item.

```
OpenForm FormName, , , "ItemID=" & ComboName
```

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141520(v=office.10).aspx

This assumes that the bound column of the combo is a numeric ID that relates to an ID in the form to be opened.

Comment: I would generally use a command button to open a form from an existing form.